# parent container encompassing the child elements

Tags: css, css-float

Im not sure why my float isn't clearing so that a child container will stay inside the parent container.

Have a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kMGQC/) to see what i mean. I want the `.shadow-wrapper` div to encompass all the other elements that follow it. How can I get the parent container to encompass the child elements?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this:

```
.shadow-wrapper {
    background-color: red;
    clear: both;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

To enclose floated elements you can use any the following:

```
float:left;
overflow:hidden;
display:table;
display:inline-block;
display:table-cell;
```

Other solution using the :after method:

```
.shadow-wrapper:after {
    clear:both;
    content:" ";
    display:block;
}
```

As you can see from this codes, clear both doesnt need to be applied everywhere, only after the last element which is floated, and therefore we can use the after method which simulates this.

http://jsfiddle.net/7wja6/

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add `float:left;` to `.shadow-wrapper`.

```
.shadow-wrapper {
    background-color: red;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kMGQC/1/

Answer (score 0):

A general rule for using floats and clears is that if you float one item, you should probably float all of its siblings too. If that seems problematic, you can add an extra div as the **last child** and clear both with that div, that should fix your issue.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="floating-thing">Hellllllooooo</div>
  <div class="non-floating-thing">Weeeeeeee</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```